# Sorting log (n) sorted subsequences in O(n log log n)

Tags: sorting, time, complexity-theory, mergesort

I've got log(n) pairwise sorted subsequences (which can differ in length) that i need to sort in O(n log log n),
but i can't figure out how. I've thought about using merge sort but that has a time complexity of O(n log n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [bottom up natural merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort). If stability is not a requirement, then use an out of order sequence to indicate the end of a run (the code will also need to use the end of an array as an end of a run). If stability is required, you'll need to create a 2nd array of counts (or pointers) to track run boundaries, to prevent two or more runs being treated as a single run due to two or more runs being in order during the merge process. Since the initial state is log(n) runs, then bottom up natural merge sort will take log(log(n)) passes for O(n log(log(n)) time complexity.